# How do I remove the corrupted Windows in another drive and keep Ubuntu only?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot mode. It worked fine for a week and now it says windows 10 is corrupted. Now I want to switch to Ubuntu only.

What should I do to remove the corrupted Windows and keep Ubuntu?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can format the unusable Windows partition as extra space for your Ubuntu system. Then rerun `sudo update-grub` so you'll see only the Ubuntu system at startup.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do..But can u elaborate steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some steps here for you if you want to reuse the Windows space for your Ubuntu system:

1. Use Gparted to format the unusable Windows partition. Make sure you choose the right partition. Format it and create an `ext4` file system on it. Give it a useful label, like "MyBigSpace". No extra flags are necessary.
2. You now have a nice bit of extra space; let's add it to your Ubuntu system. Let's say that the partition is called `/dev/sda2`. Create a *mount point* for your partition: `mkdir ~/mybigspace` if you want to use it for just your own user, or `sudo mkdir /mnt/bigspace` if you want a system-wide partition. If you're the only user of your system, there is not much difference, and you can create a mount point anywhere.
3. Now hook the space up to your system: `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /path/to/your/mountpoint`. Fill in the right partition you formatted in step 1, and the mount point you created in step 2.
4. If the `mount` command ends with no error, enter `df` and find the partition. It is ready for use! However, it will be unaccessible after a reboot. In order not to have to enter the mount command after every, add a line in `/etc/fstab` at the end like:

   `/dev/sda2 /path/to/your/mountpoint     ext4     rw  0     0`

Comment: I don't know why but Gparted throws and error 'unable to locate package' Can I use Gnome disk Utility?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you ought to be able to  `sudo apt install gparted` without any trouble on 19.10.

Comment: I don't know i'm noob, tried various methods still 'unable to locate package'

Comment: What is the output of `apt policy gparted` on your system?

Comment: N: Unable to locate package gparted